# Access pointer values in assembly

Tags: opencv, assembly, x86, nasm

I have a `Mat image` and i am loading an image into it `image = imread(argv[1]) CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);`

What i am trying to do is pass the pointer to the first data `image.data` to an assembly program. I want to access the RGB values on the passed pointer. I can get to the pointer in the assembly but don't know how to access the RGB values. Is there a way to do it in assembly?

I tried doing it in opencv with this

```
unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(image.data);
        for (int j = 0; j < image.rows; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < image.cols; i++) {
                cout << "Step: " << image.step << endl;
                unsigned int b = input[image.step * j + i];
                unsigned int g = input[image.step * j + i + 1];
                unsigned int r = input[image.step * j + i + 2];
             }
        }
```

and it worked but i can't use the step in assembly.

In assembly i can save the pointer to a register

```
mov ebx,[ebp + 16]
```

and i want to access the RGB values something like this

```
mov ebx,[ ebx green value]
mov ecx,[ ebx red value]
mov edx,[ ebx blue value]
```

But don't know how to get the position of the values

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Do you want to know how to do e.g. `input[image.step * j + i]`? That's just array indexing. Also, what architecture? Show attempts, if you got any.

Comment: I want to be able to work with the RGB values of image.data in assembly

Comment: `[ebx]` is blue, `[ebx+1]` is green, `[ebx+2]` is red as per your C code. What's the issue? PS: your code is broken, it should probably say `3*i`. PS #2: your `input` is `char`, not `int` so your asm code should either use byte registers or zero extension.